# How do i wrap text in next kine in order to fit this table in landscape orientation in overleaf?

Tags: latex, overleaf

How do i wrap text in next line in order to fit this table in landscape orientation in the latex document. Need to wrap text particularly in column  7, 8 and column 9.
Attached image is how I want it to look in overload....but in landscape orientation.

[image: Attached image is how I want it to look in overload....but in landscape orientation]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,comment}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\remark}[1]{{\color{red} \large \bf~#1~}}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Exhibit}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Exhibit}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{landscape}
\newpage
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
 \footnotesize
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{Cash Flow}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc p{0.2\linewidth} p{0.3\linewidth}cccclrl}
    \toprule
SNo. & Funding Date & Round Name & Funding Amount (USD) & Round Post-Money Valuation (USD) & Institutional Investors & Angel Investors & Lead Investor & Total Funding (USD) & Revenue Multiple \\ 
        1 & Jul 26, 2021 & Series A & 2,50,00,000 & 10,39,39,264 & WestBridge,Accel,Tanglin Venture Partners, Calabasas Capital,AngelList,Sparkle Fund, Konark Trust,MMPL Trust,GP Partners & Ashneer Grover,Abhimanyu Munjal,Kushal Nahata,Ashish Singhal,Ankur Ashwin Shah,Ashish Sharma,Karthik Bhat,Gautam Kumar & WestBridge,Accel, Tanglin Venture  Partners & 2,85,70,159 & ~ \\ 
        2 & Oct 29, 2020 & Seed & 33,60,820 & 1,36,14,263 & Accel,Titan Capital,QED Innovation,Blue  Wolf Capital Partners,ICICI Bank,Sparkle Fund & Sumit Maniyar,Ramakanth Sharma,Gaurav Agarwal,Nitin Gupta,Akshat Sharma,Harish Kumar Goel,Akhil Paul,Pramod Kumar Saraf,Chitransh Sahai,Kunal Bahl,Viswamani Ganesh,Ashish Santhalia,Anjali Bansal,Dilip KumarKarodimal Khandelwal,Rohit Bansal & Accel & 2,85,70,159 & 30.2 \\ 
        3 & Nov 16, 2019 & Seed & 2,09,339 & 14,86,494 & Titan Capital & Rajesh Razdan,Ajay Garg,Mitesh Damania,Bipin Kumar Shah,Sunder Nookala,Kunal Bahl,Rohit Bansal & Titan Capital & 2,85,70,159 & 68.6 \\ 
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Did you test the document as posted in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you removed the long wordy columns and moved them to another table. Then match everything by ID. To let table contain long text, you get very tall rows. I don't think it looks correct.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}   % \usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Exhibit}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Exhibit}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
    \renewcommand{\theadalign}{ct}
    \caption{Cash Flow}
    \label{tab:addlabel}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcc *2{r} *3{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} rc}
      \toprule
      SNo.
      & \thead{Funding\\Date}
      & \thead{Round\\Name}
      & \thead{Funding\\Amount\\(USD)}
      & \thead{Round\\Post-Money\\Valuation\\(USD)}
      & \thead{Institutional\\Investors}
      & \thead{Angel\\Investors}
      & \thead{Lead\\Investor}
      & \thead{Total\\Funding\\(USD)}
      & \thead{Revenue\\Multiple} \\
      \midrule
      1
      & Jul 26, 2021
      & Series A
      & 2,50,00,000
      & 10,39,39,264
      & WestBridge, Accel, Tanglin Venture Partners, Calabasas Capital, AngelList, Sparkle Fund, Konark Trust, MMPL Trust, GP Partners
      & Ashneer Grover, Abhimanyu Munjal, Kushal Nahata, Ashish Singhal, Ankur Ashwin Shah, Ashish Sharma, Karthik Bhat, Gautam Kumar
      & WestBridge, Accel, Tanglin Venture Partners
      & 2,85,70,159
      & ~ \\ 
      2
      & Oct 29, 2020
      & Seed
      & 33,60,820
      & 1,36,14,263
      & Accel, Titan Capital, QED Innovation, Blue Wolf Capital Partners, ICICI Bank, Sparkle Fund
      & Sumit Maniyar,Ramakanth Sharma,Gaurav Agarwal,Nitin Gupta,Akshat Sharma,Harish Kumar Goel,Akhil Paul, Pramod Kumar Saraf, Chitransh Sahai, Kunal Bahl, Viswamani Ganesh, Ashish Santhalia, Anjali Bansal, Dilip KumarKarodimal Khandelwal, Rohit Bansal
      & Accel
      & 2,85,70,159
      & 30.2 \\ 
      3
      & Nov 16, 2019
      & Seed
      & 2,09,339
      & 14,86,494
      & Titan Capital
      & Rajesh Razdan,Ajay Garg,Mitesh Damania,Bipin Kumar Shah,Sunder Nookala,Kunal Bahl,Rohit Bansal
      & Titan Capital
      & 2,85,70,159
      & 68.6 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```